# Associate integer with devise user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add an integer value to each Devise user to keep track of credits, which cannot be edited by the user. After doing some research it seems like I should create a credits model with belongs_to user. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like overkill to create a separate `Credit` model, since all an instance will hold is a value and a reference to a user. I've posted an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for an entirely new model, since all you need to is a single integer associated with each user. Try adding a `credits` attribute to your `User` model:

```
# from command line
rails generate migration AddCreditsToUser credits:integer
rake db:migrate

# app/models/user.rb
attr_accessible :credits
```

It shouldn't matter whether your model is Devise-backed or not, since the `credits` attribute operates outside of Devise.

Comment: Thank you! Still trying to wrap my head around using the command line to do important tasks like this.