# Referencing a variable associated with a Devise user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an integer associated with a Devise user to keep track of credits.

In user.rb:

```
attr_accessible :credits
```

However, being the dumb-dumb that I am (this is my second day with Rails) I'm not accessing it correctly.

Here is my crappy code from a page.html.erb file, I've tried over a dozen variations of this:

```
<h2>You have: </h2> <%= @user.credits =%> <h2> Credits </h2>
```

And it yields this error:

```
undefined method `credits' for nil:NilClass
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: And what's not working here?

Comment: Edited to add the error, sorry about that.

Comment: Where do you define `@user`?

Comment: Ok, so the `@user` have to be defined in controller. If you're looking for a device's  helper, it's called `current_user`

Comment: current_user.credits is not working either. I created credits in the command line (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808520/associate-integer-with-devise-user)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44027/discussion-between-bartosz-and-sciguy77)

Comment: show me your association at from model